# Difference Between df.wirte and CREATE TABLE USING

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have always been under the impression that the following code create a Delta table,

```
data.write.format("delta").save("/path/to/delta-table")
```

This creates the files, sure, however, I noticed today that when I look at the Data section of Databricks, under the `hive_metastore`, this table does not show up.

In order for this table to show up there, I have to do something like,

```
CREATE TABLE some_table USING DELTA LOCATION "/path/to/delta-table"
```

What exactly is going on here? Was I wrong in my understanding that the `.write` operation creates a table? What is the difference between these commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html) has following methods:

> **def save(path: String): Unit**
>
> Saves the content of the DataFrame at the specified path.
>
> **def saveAsTable(tableName: String): Unit**
>
> Saves the content of the DataFrame as the specified table.

What you did by `.save("/path/to/delta-table")` was saving the data in delta format in the filesystem. In order for the table to be visible in data catalog (aka. metastore) you need to run `CREATE TABLE` providing the location.

You can write data using `.saveAsTable("delta-table")` - that would write the data under a path managed by the metastore and register the table in one step.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have a quick follow up question: if I execute a `CREATE TABLE` command on top of data that has been saved using `.save()`, does it affect the structure or nature of this data in any way? I ask this because I still have users who come in and directly run queries on top of the files.

Comment: It does not affect the structure. Regardless of whether the table is created on top of that or not you can read directly from the path with `SELECT * FROM delta.\`/path/to/delta-table\``.

Comment: Thank you. I think you've answered my question perfectly.